# The Height of space between two div

Tags: css

I have code that embedded video within text. However the space between the title and the video 
is too high.

```
<section id="Number"> 
 <article class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="sub_header"> 
        <h2>ABC Number</h2>
```

The following video will be saparated too high from ABC Number with only one line (but the line seems too high)

```
        <div class="video">
        <div class="vdwrapper">
        <div class="fluidvids" style="width:100%;position:relative;padding-top:56.2%">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/87745355?                     
         title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="100%" height="100%" 
         frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;top:-0.85px;left:0"></iframe>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>




      <div class="featurecont"> <p> Number is a proxy phone number assigned to you when 
you sign up on with your regular mobile number.</p>
       <p>Number can be used in many ways, you can register your Number as a separate   
profile on can keep your real phone number entirely anonymous. You can share your 
Number with lesser known people or acquaintances that you meet at various places, or 
while posting Ads. This way, people can only reach you on and cannot call you on your 
personal mobile number.

</p>

 <p>Another cool advantage of Number is that your Number can also be transferred to   
 non-SIM devices like , etc. This would allow your kids and family members to stay    
 connected with you and have safe and secure communications.</p></div>  
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

The css is as follows:

```
.chaatzvideo {
position: relative;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
background: url('../images/tv.png') center center no-repeat;
background-size: 78%;
}

.row {
margin-left: -20px;
*zoom: 1;
}

.span12 {
width: 980px;
}

.vdwrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 75%;
}

.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
width: 980px;
}

#Number .sub_header h2{background: url('../images/features/Chaatz-Notop.png') no-repeat    
center top; padding-bottom: 50px; padding-top:110px}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having padding top and bottom for "#Number .sub_header h2"... try to use something like this

```
#Number .sub_header h2 {
    background: url('../images/features/Chaatz-Notop.png') no-repeat center top;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top:20px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eNby3/)**

Comment: I think it is the size of the Chaatz-Notop.png. I have change to
    
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top:20px
    
However, the height is same. Can I make the video to overlap a little on the image, that will reduce the space height

Comment: Change the padding, still not working. It is the image makes it saparated from the text so high. Can I overlap the text a litter with
../images/features/Chaatz-Notop.png

Comment: yes u can.. try to give position:absolute; bottom:-30px; z-index:999;  give bottom value negatively for text and give z-index value less than text...